# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"} when trying to view "Sent" msgs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm almost there and I'm trying to figure out the rest of the simple_private_messages plugin. Anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Here is my rake routes output

```
delete_selected_user_messages POST       /users/:user_id/messages/delete_select
ed(.:format)    messages#delete_selected
                 user_messages GET        /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)
                messages#index
                               POST       /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)
                messages#create
              new_user_message GET        /users/:user_id/messages/new(.:format)
                messages#new
             edit_user_message GET        /users/:user_id/messages/:id/edit(.:fo
rmat)           messages#edit
                  user_message GET        /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)
                messages#show
                               PUT        /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)
                messages#update
                               DELETE     /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)
                messages#destroy
                         users GET        /users(.:format)
                users#index
                               POST       /users(.:format)
                users#create
                      new_user GET        /users/new(.:format)
                users#new
                     edit_user GET        /users/:id/edit(.:format)
                users#edit
                          user GET        /users/:id(.:format)
                users#show
                               PUT        /users/:id(.:format)
                users#update
                               DELETE     /users/:id(.:format)
                users#destroy
```

Here's my routes.db

```
  resources :users do
             resources :messages do
               collection do
                 post :delete_selected
               end
             end
           end



  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts do
  resources :comments

end
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

and here's my _sent.html.erb

```
<h2>Sent</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete?</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Sent</th>
    </tr>
    <% if @messages.size == 0 %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                No messages
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% else %>
        <% for message in @messages %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "delete[]", message.id %></td>
                <td><%= link_to h(message.subject), user_message_path(@user, message) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to h(message.recipient_id), user_path(message.recipient) %></td>
              <td><%=h message.created_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <%= submit_tag "Delete" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
<%= link_to "Inbox", user_messages_path(@user)%>
```

I'm trying to get this link working (localhost:3000/users/2/messages?mailbox=sent)
but I am getting this error message

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most probable cause of your error is this line

```
user_path(message.recipient)
```

There is a message where recipient is nil.  Check the db if there is such a record.

Comment: when I was testing earlier today, there were some messages sent to nill recipients. Would deleting all of those messages solve it and how can I do that? I thought it was caused by something else.

Comment: hmm. you can fire up the console and run `Message.where(recipient_id: nil).delete_all` to delete all of them.  After running this and you still get the same error, let me know here :)

Comment: that worked!.... thanks. But how can I prevent future messages from going into nil recipients? Right now, my "To" field is just an open text field so users need to type the username as exact.

Comment: hmm add a validation that recipient_id must not be nil so messages wont be created in such cases.

Comment: sure. add `validates :recipient_id, presence: true` in your message model.

Comment: A user "3" can just type in a http://localhost:3000/users/7/messages/new to get into another user's message link and send a message. Do you know how I can prevent that easily?

Comment: hmm. you can add a `before_filter` that checks the current user's id against the requested one. or just use current_user.messages so it won't matter what number they type in.

Comment: what would go after "before_filter"? I just tried and got some undefined errors (this is my last question)

Comment: it's a little more complex than that.  first create a method called `ensure_current_user`, the add `before_filter :ensure_current_user`, then in that method, check for `params[:user_id] == current_user.id`